# Powershell - Remove (Default) registry key?

Tags: powershell, registry

I see you can remove items by running:

```
Remove-Item -Path hkcu:\CurrentVersion
```

But I tried

```
Remove-Item -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Testing\(Default)'
```

But that did not work. I also tried

```
Remove-Item -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Testing\' -name '(Default)'
```

Which also did not work. Any ideas how I can remove a (Default) registry key via powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you try to delete it from the registry .msc console?

I think isn't possible to delete the default value for a key.

Comment: Correct. You cannot delete the `(Default)` value without deleting the key itself.

Comment: I don't know if this was once true, but in Windows 10 you can definitely can delete the default value in regedit.exe.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating on @papo's answer - If OP wished to clear (nullify) the contents of the `(Default)` registry value and use the standard way how registry are accessed in PowerShell, oneliner would be

```
$(Get-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Testing").OpenSubKey("", $true).DeleteValue("")
```

- `Get-Item -Path` fetches the *RegistryKey* object for reading
- `OpenSubKey("", $true)` reopens the same key with write permissions
- `DeleteValue("")` clears the default (in .NET treated as unnamed) value

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

(Below line is an answer for removing *(Default)* as a Key name),
This is the answer for removing default Value: *(Default)* from a registry Key by PowerShell.

It's supposedly a bug in PS, since v1. Now as of 2018, with v5.1, bug is still present.
Actually `Remove-Item -Path 'Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Testing\' -name '(Default)'` is wrong for the reason that (Default) is not a Key, but a Property,
but let's say most of us tried:
`Remove-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Testing -Name '(Default)'`
and this should have worked.

Luckily, as with many PS Cmdlets, function of *Remove-ItemProperty* could be  substituted by use of a Method. In this case DeleteValue() Method invoked on a RegistryKey Object.
There is a small hiccup, as a Key, obtained by Get-Item is Read-only. But another Method, OpenSubKey() can be used to get writable access to a Key.

```
function Remove-ItemPropertyDefault {
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
  Param (
    [parameter(ParameterSetName='Path', Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [String]$Path,
    [parameter(ParameterSetName='Key', Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]$Key
  )
    if ($Path) {$Key = Get-Item -LiteralPath $Path}
    $ParentKey = Get-Item -LiteralPath $Key.PSParentPath
    $KeyName = $Key.PSChildName
    ($ParentKey.OpenSubKey($KeyName, $True)).DeleteValue('')
}
```

- SupportsShouldProcess - to allow *-WhatIf* argument
- Param ... etc - to allow pipeline use, both String and RegistryKey inputs and for sanity check
- $ParentKey - get parent key on which a method is used to open original key in writable mode
- $KeyName - String value of the original Key name without path
- [OpenSubKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d(v=vs.110).aspx) - will get a child Key of a Key, also offers second argument to choose write access
- DeleteValue() with an empty string as an argument. Inside of the RegistryKey Object's methods, (Default) value is referenced by an empty string.

Use:
`Remove-ItemPropertyDefault Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Testing`
or
`Get-Item Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Testing | Remove-ItemPropertyDefault`
or
`$k = Get-Item Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Testing
Remove-ItemPropertyDefault -Key $k`
Of course if you don't need or want a function, just take those three lines from it and use it in your code.
This is a nice [article which gave me this idea.](http://www.powertheshell.com/removedefaultvalue/)

---

The OP possibly asked about removing a **Key** with the name **(Default)**, 
not a Default value from a key as people landing here mostly searched for.
In that case a -LiteralPath should be used, because Brackets are considered special characters in -Path argument, whilst -LiteralPath takes their literal meaning:

```
Remove-Item -LiteralPath 'Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Testing\(Default)'
```

or brackets needs to be escaped:

```
Remove-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Testing\`(Default`)"
```

(*) Single quote can't be used then, but double-quotes, or no quotes must be used for escape character to work.

Or lastly, if the Path is not literal, a function could be used to escape a string, not known at the time of writing the code:

```
Remove-Item -Path ([Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape('Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Testing\(Default)'))
```

(*) this will add ` in front of characters with a special meaning in Path argument